Using Jest to unit test contentful-export library
I'm having some difficulties testing my usage of contentfulExport. I've written a script, called via a GitHub action, that exports my Contentful environment, and then calls a function to upload the data to an S3 bucket if the export is successful.
import { getInput } from "@actions/core";
import contentfulExport from "contentful-export";
import { uploadFile } from "./utils";

const local_backup_path = "/tmp";
const file_name = Date.now().toString() + ".json";
const bucketName = getInput("s3BucketName");

const options = {
  spaceId: getInput("contentfulSpaceId"),
  environmentId: "master",
  managementToken: getInput("contentfulApiToken"),
  deliveryToken: getInput("contentfulDeliveryToken"),
  contentFile: file_name,
  exportDir: local_backup_path,
  useVerboseRenderer: false,
  saveFile: true,
};

contentfulExport(options)
  .then((result) => {
    console.log("Your space data has been downloaded!");

    // Save file to AWS S3
    console.log("Preparing file for AWS `S3`!");
    uploadFile(result, bucketName, file_name);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("An error occurred", err);
  });

I'm wanting to write a couple of small tests using Jest in order to test what happens if the export succeeds, or fails. I'm really struggling to figure out how to do this, when I expect contentfulExport to have been called, Jest thinks it's an object rather than a function.
How can I test the success of contentfulExport and what happens in the then block afterwards?
This is what I've been trying.
import contentfulExport from "contentful-export";
import { uploadFile } from '../../../.github/actions/contentful/scripts/utils';

jest.mock("contentful-export", () => {
  return {
    contentfulExport: jest.mock,
  };
});

jest.mock('../../../.github/actions/contentful/scripts/utils', () => {
  return {
    uploadFile: jest.fn()
  }
});


describe("upload", () => {
  it("should log a success message when the space data has been downloaded", async () => {
    expect(contentfulExport).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    
    expect(uploadFile).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
})

This is the error that gives me
expect(received).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

Received has type:  object
Received has value: {"contentfulExport": [Function mock]}

Another try:
it("should log a success message when the space data has been downloaded", async () => {     
    contentfulExport(options).then((result) => {       
        expect(uploadFile).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);     
    });       
});

This gives the error:
TypeError: (0, contentfulExport.default) is not a function

